# Unpickle a data structure Vs. build by calling readlines()

Tags: python, performance, pickle

I have a use case where I need to build a list from the lines in a file.  This operation will be performed potentially 100s of times on a distributed network.  I've been using the obvious solution of:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    ds = f.readlines()
```

I just had the thought that perhaps I would be better off creating this list once, pickling it into a file and then using that file to unpickle the data on each node.

Would there be any performance increase if I did this?

Comment: My money is on `readlines` ... but I've been wrong before :) -- if you actually had to process the lines in some way, then maybe pickle would be faster ...

Comment: I actually have to call a .strip() on each line

Comment: Do the simplest thing that works.  Don't waste time trying to optimize it unless it's going to be a bottleneck.

Comment: Sure, it may fail the CR for not being the simplest.  But it still is an interesting Computer Science / Python question IMO

Comment: You don't have to call strip - your_list = f.read().split('\n') (assuming you were stripping for the newline)

Comment: Why not just do `list(f)`? Since `f` is just an iterator over lines, `list(f)` is a `list` of those same lines. (That's half the reason `readlines` was deprecated. The other half is that you almost never want to do this anyway—just iterate over the file without creating the list in the first place.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Would there be any performance increase if I did this?

Test it and see!

```
try:
    import cPickle as pickle
except:
    import pickle
import timeit

def lines():
    with open('lotsalines.txt') as f:
         return f.readlines()

def pickles():
    with open('lotsalines.pickle', 'rb') as f:
        return pickle.load(f)

ds = lines()
with open('lotsalines.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    t = timeit.timeit(lambda: pickle.dump(ds, file=f, protocol=-1), number=1)
print('pickle.dump: {}'.format(t))

print('readlines:   {}'.format(timeit.timeit(lines, number=10))
print('pickle.load: {}'.format(timeit.timeit(pickles, number=10))
```

My 'lotsalines.txt' file is just that source duplicated until it's 655360 lines long, or 15532032 bytes.

Apple Python 2.7.2:

```
readlines:   0.640027999878
pickle.load: 2.67698192596
```

And the pickle file is 19464748 bytes.

Python.org 3.3.0:

```
readlines:   1.5357899703085423
pickle.load: 1.5975534357130527
```

And it's 20906546 bytes.

So, Python 3 has sped up `pickle` quite a bit over Python 2, at least if you use pickle protocol 3, but it's still nowhere near as fast as a simple `readlines`. (And `readlines` has gotten a lot slower in 3.x, as well as being deprecated.)

But really, if you've got performance concerns, you should consider whether you need the `list` in the first place. A quick test shows that building a `list` of this size is almost half the cost of the `readlines` (timing `list(range(655360))` in 3.x, `list(xrange(655360))` in 2.x). And it uses a ton of memory (which is probably actually why it's slow, too). If you don't actually need the `list`—and usually you don't—just iterate over the file, getting lines as you need them.

Comment: Thanks for an actual answer to the question and showing me how to time things in the future